# Issue in Binding Text with( Rx and windows Phone)

Tags: windows-phone-7, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactiveui

In my application i am using Reactive extensions for making web request .  What my issue is, i am making two requests. In the first request i will get a url from the sever and by using that url i am sending another  request for fetching image and description. In my first request apart from url i will get the title and date related information. So what i am doing is i will parse the data in my model class and from there i will call the other request. Here when i receive response i will add that in to my class object   that can hold the result. And when the complete(onnext,error,complete) portion of my first request reaches i will get the both result in my property. But the issue is that the corresponding change ,ie the result of second web request is not reflecting on my UI. Please anyone help me to avoid this issue.

Comment: Are you using a `SelectMany` call to tie both of your requests together into a single query?

Comment: No i am not using Select Many... I think my issue is the result of first request will populate and it will reflects ui.. only after that the req for second is coming. Sp i can see the result on OnCompleted; But not refelecting that on ui.. I am looking for a solution to that.. Reassigning the value in OnCompleted will solve my issue temporarily but it think it’s not the fix what i am looking for..Can u suggest any gud way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would structure your code - it's not a complete solution as you'll need to fill in the blanks a bit - but it should make it easier.

I started with the assumption that you would have classes like this:

```
public class X
{
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    public System.Drawing.Image Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Z
{
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public System.Drawing.Image Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now I created these two functions:

```
Func<IObservable<X>> getX =
    () =>
        {
            /* you must write this code */
        };

Func<X, IObservable<Y>> getYFromX =
    x =>
        {
            /* you must write this code */
        };
```

They represent the two parts of your code.

Here's how to join them together:

```
IObservable<Z> getZ =
    from x in getX()
    from y in getYFromX(x)
    select new Z()
    {
        Uri = x.Uri,
        Title = x.Title,
        Date = x.Date,
        Image = y.Image,
        Description = y.Description,
    };
```

The Rx magic using `SelectMany` here joins your two sub-parts together. Hopefully it'll be easier for you to define the `getX` & `getYFromX` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a) jumping back to the UI thread using `ObserveOnDispatcher()`? and b) raising `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` events on the properties of the class you are setting as the DataContext?

Comment: The hierarchy is like this 
In the MainViewModel i added my property with the class type as model class. In my mainviewmodel i implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged. Yup i am using observe on dispatcher.

Comment: @NithaPaul - Is the request definitely completing? Can you describe the object graph to the property that is not being displayed (eg. `MainViewModel.Something.Title`)?

Comment: I think my issue is the result of first request will populate and it will reflects ui.. only after that the req for second is coming. Sp i can see the result on OnCompleted; But not refelecting that on ui.. I am looking for a solution to that.. Reassigning the value in OnCompleted will solve my issue temporarily but it think it’s not the fix what i am looking for..Can u suggest any gud way to solve this issue?